# Steam does not start on Debian 10 Buster

Tags: debian, steam

My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster) Stable x86_64, computer is Thinkpad x230, with Intel i5-3320M (4) @ 3.300GHz CPU and Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller GPU, the kernel version is 4.19.0-9-amd64.

Yesterday I ran apt update && apt upgrade. I left steam turned on overnight to download a game. Today I woke up and saw steam was not active anymore, and after I tried launching it, I got this message: https://pastebin.com/iPJJS1Bp

After which, Steam is not active anymore, that is it turns on for a second and then exits. Here's what I tried:

1. Purging steam and reinstalling it + deleting the .steam directory - no effect.
2. Running steam from ~/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam - I get Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so. I tried few suggestions on the internet, but they were very old entries and largely irrelevant.
3. Suggestions from here: https://wiki.debian.org/Steam.

   - STEAM_RUNTIME_PREFER_HOST_LIBRARIES=0 steam returns https://pastebin.com/mPjACUrR and then also just shuts down.
   - STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam launches steam, but then just freezes with this output https://pastebin.com/F2tv96LG.
   - Ran # apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers libglx-mesa0:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, but they were already installed (I have Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller, the laptop is Thinkpad x230).
4. https://askubuntu.com/questions/345120/why-doesnt-steam-start
5. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/6bm0as/steam_on_debian_stretch_wont_load_fatal_error/
6. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/13jwam/fatal_error_failed_to_load_steamuiso_how_to_fix/

If I skipped any relevant information/logs please say so, and I will do my best to provide them. I wanted to include apt logs, but I only found ones dating from today.

EDIT: After running `file * | grep ELF | cut -d: -f1 | LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. xargs ldd | grep 'not found' | sort | uniq` I found that I'm missing 2 libraries - libnm-glib.so.4 and libnm-util.so.2, but I can't find them anywhere in the repositories (they're supposedly in the unstable repositories, but even when i run `apt -t unstable libnm-glib4` it doesn't find the package. Where exactly do I get these from? On the wiki it says that

> It won't use its runtime and will only use the system libraries. The necessary packages to run entirely without the runtime have been removed in Debian 10/Buster, but Steam will automatically use specific newer system libraries in place of its runtime if they're available.

Is there anything I can do about this?